# Vaadin auto injection and routing issues

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am working for the first time with UI and Vaadin in a Spring Boot project.
I have a Flow class on these lines

```
 @Route("subscribe/:id)
   public class RegisterNewMember extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {
     private final MembershipService service;
     private final MemberRepository repository;

     public RegisterNewMember(MembershipService service, MemberRepository repository) {

        this.service = service;
        this.repository = repository;
         ....
    }
    And my service class
    public class MembershipService {

    private final MemberRepository repository;
  

    public MemberDTO addNewMember(Member member) {
        MemberDTO memberDTO = repository.save(member); // <---- NullPointerException
        ...
        ...
    }.
```

..

This is as plain vanilla a Spring Boot app as it can get. But with Vaadin, I am seeing my Service class is autowired absolutely fine, but the Repository is null. I hacked to inject the Repository in the top class where I only passed Service class initially in the constructor, just to see if that resolves the problem.

Java Version: 17 Spring Boot: 3.1.0 and Vaadin 24

Comment: What exactly is `RegisterNewMember`? If it's just a simple class, then
it will not partake in DI.  The most prominent things taking part in DI
outside of what spring already does for you is `Route` and `RouterLayout`.

Comment: RegisterNewMember is a Route implementing VerticalLayout, sorry I should have elaborated

Comment: So what is the correlation between the `MembershipService` and the
`SubscriptionService`? Is the repo properly setup?  Does
`SubscriptionService` actually have a c'tor, that sets the repo?  I'd
also suggest to remove the second part from your question.  SO is not
a forum, but a QA page. If you have multiple questions add multiple.
Also "what is best" is opinion based and a bad match for QA.

Comment: Sheesh, I am on a goofing spree here. SubscriptionService was my old name for MembershipService. `RegisterNewMember' ->MembershipService->MemberRepository.save()

Comment: As a plain vanilla Spring Boot Service, I have tested the service and repository to perform basic CRUD operations. The Vaadin flows came in later

Comment: And `MemberService` has proper spring annotations and can be found by spring boot for DI? Same goes for the repo?